# Android Studio:- The Music is changing after a song is finished does not behave properly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, lag, android-seekbar, android-music-player

I am aiming to make a simple music player app and I am new to android development
I wanted that the app should play the next song when the current song is finished so I paste the code of next Button inside. It does not work according to what I needed it changes the song but the seekbar is stuck at the starting point.....Also when I touch the seek bar the app crashes and reopen.... I am stuck in this for quite a long time so I have attached github link of the public repo.Also the app is providing a bit laggy experience and sometimes stop working

PLS help
[Project Repo](https://github.com/Nishant-Khatri/Tune-Tide-)
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You might be updating UI from  worker thread

Comment: And how to implement it ?!??